# What's the continuity between the two Knight Rider TV series?

Tags: knight-rider

The pilot episode of the [2008 Knight Rider TV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1213404/) went to great lengths to establish continuity with [the original series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083437/).  For example, the 2008 Michael Knight is the son of the original (Hasselhoff), and KITT (3000) is the successor to KITT (2000).

It seems like this continuity was discarded throughout the (single) season.  In particular, there were several statements that seemed to infer that KITT (3000) was the first AI of its type, when really it was just an improved version of KITT (2000).  Towards the end of the season, it is revealed that

> KITT (3000) was created to try and improve the AI for KARR.

Does this fit into the original storyline in some way that I'm missing?  If not, is there any information available about why they moved away from keeping continuity after putting so much effort into it with the pilot?  (For example, commentary or interviews - not speculation).

Answer (score 5):

In the original series, [KARR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KARR_%28Knight_Rider%29) was a prototype of [KITT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KARR_%28Knight_Rider%29) that had some serious defects.

In the reboot, KARR is said to be a prototype of a different kind - a transforming cybernetic exo-skeleton.

So, the two references to KARR are to different prototypes, which perhaps supports a perceived lack of continuity.

However, I'm wondering if there's another explanation ...

... the original KARR project worked to create an prototype AI with a detective like focus - note the way the original (production version) KITT was used for research, investigation and forensics.

... the reboot KARR project seemed much more of a military weapon - note the off road capabilities and weaponry, plus the inclusion of tactics and strategy in the programming of KARR.

Could it therefore be said that the KITT (3000) was the first of it's type because it was the first production model of a military A.I.?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell, Knight Rider 2008 disregards all other sequels and is something of a reboot itself.

Comment: No, that's not correct.  As I said in the question, the pilot goes to great lengths to establish continuity with the new series.  Hasselhoff even makes an appearance at the end.

Comment: Yes I realize that. That's why I said it disregards all **sequels**. It reboots everything that happened after the original.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question, then?  I'm asking why the continuity that was established in the pilot of the 2008 series is seemingly dropped throughout that series.

Comment: they tried to apeal to the fans of the original by promising continuity, then went off and ditched it when it became too hard to preserve... Which is typical of remakes.